# react-native - Modal always visible

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog

I know there is a question here in stackoverflow [react native modal always visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57277470/react-native-modal-always-visible) but didn't solve my problem.

My code:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {Text, View, Modal} from 'react-native'

export default function App() {
    return (
        <Modal animationType="slide" visible={false}>
            <Text>Hello World :)</Text>
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

the problem is I hardcoded `visible` to `false` but again it is visible. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example here for you with `react-native modal` and using you code,

https://snack.expo.io/@waheed25/modalexample

You are rendering only modal

if it still not works for you add your code in the same snack.

Comment: Can you please go to ios tab.

Comment: Yeah that's working there and in android too. But I want to test it in web all the time.